# Why would list.remove return false other than the item not being in the collection c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I noticed the documentation for the return value of [List<T>.Remove(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0#:%7E:text=true%20if%20item,Implements) says:

> Returns: true if item is successfully removed; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if item was not found in the List.

To me this implies `Remove(T)` could fail to remove an item for a reason *other than the item not being found in the list*. Am I reading into this too much or are there another reasons `List<T>.Remove(T)` could fail and if so what are they?

Comment: It might be just bad documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/dae14279dd0672adead5de00ac8f117dcf74c184/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L823-L831

Comment: @gunr2171 I did wonder that since it's the exact same as the docs for `ICollection<T>.Remove(T)`.

Comment: Remove() fails if you try to remove an item while enumerating the list in a foreach loop. In a for loop, it won't fail, but loop index becomes unusable as the items have changed positions.

Comment: @Shameel Brilliant, thanks! Do you know if that's the only other reason it could fail?

Comment: @Commonaught, I haven't come across any other reason it could fail.

Comment: Seems like bad docs. `List<T>.Remove<T>(T)` finds the index of the element and tries to remove it and returns `false` if it's not found. But the `IList.Remove(object)` will check if the object is "compatible" and return `false` before trying to find it if it's not. If it is compatible, it'll cast the `object` to a `T` and call `Remove<T>`.

Comment: `List` is not thread safe, so if anyone else removed the same item while you were going to do that, voila!

Comment: Is it appropriate for me to summarize the answers given in the comments as an answer and then accept it?

Comment: @Commonaught, I think that would be fine if not preferred if you can craft it well-enough.